# How To Search For Values In excel Then Test Each value With Condition and get the total

Tags: excel, filter, excel-formula

lets say if the following data

| person | value | number of days |
| --- | --- | --- |
| P1 | 54646 | 126 |
| P1 | 5465465 | 60 |
| P1 | 4654654 | 50 |
| P2 | 4654654 | 600 |
| P2 | 4654654 | 40 |
| P1 | 4654654 | 100 |
| P3 | 4654654 | 50 |

i want a formula to get for example total value from only **P1** and **>= 100 in numbers of days**
in on cell
i know **SUMIF** and **LOOKUP** Formula but i Dont Know How to combine Them to get the work done
thank you

Comment: Have you researched SUMIFS yet?

Comment: @BigBen yes, and im on it

Comment: Feel free to delete the question then as SUMIFS is a basic Excel formula and of little value as a question on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming

- your range top left cell is A1
- you want the sum of column B

you can use this formula.

```
=SUMIFS($B$2:$B$8,$A$2:$A$8,"P1",$C$2:$C$8,">=100")
```